# extracting array element from joined DQL query in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using a joined query to extract user data together with the role data from an associated table.  The query is extracting the data, but I cannot work out how to extract a specific element from the join.

**query from repo:**

```
public function loadAllUsers()
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u', 'r')
        ->leftJoin('u.roles', 'r')
        ->addOrderBy('u.username', 'ASC');

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**my twig template section:**

```
            {% for user in users %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.firstname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.lastLogged.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.roles.name }}</td> <!-- insert role name in here -->
                    <td>{{ user.isactive }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

**output from a twig dump** of the user object sent to the template

```
users {#264 ▼
  -id: 1
  -username: "admin"
  -password: "$2y$12$9f76e741dd03a517a5207OkX/gjsP3mif2RxJIs00WyVUj4c3jYPS"
  -firstname: "Matt"
  -lastname: "HB"
  -isActive: true
  -email: "aaaa@aaaa.aaa"
  -lastLogged: DateTime {#262 ▶}
  -salt: "9f76e741dd03a517a5207b91476079c7"
  -roles: PersistentCollection {#280 ▼
    -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
    -owner: users {#264}
    -association: array:20 [ …20]
    -em: EntityManager {#121 …10}
    -backRefFieldName: "users"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#265 …}
    -isDirty: false
    -initialized: true
    -coll: ArrayCollection {#281 ▼
      -_elements: array:1 [▼
        0 => roles {#288 ▼
          -id: 6
          -name: "super_admin"
          -role: "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
          -users: PersistentCollection {#289 ▶}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Ive tried the following lines to no avail. I need the role name for the user.

```
{{ user.roles.name }}
{{ user.roles.coll.name ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) in your twig template to iterate over the individual roles like this:

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
    {{ role.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i might not have explained myself very well.  Ill alter my question to clarify.

Comment: Still, according to the dump, you have multiple roles per user. That is the reason why you cannot just print one of them but have to use a loop.

Comment: ah true! I forgot theres a third table that contains the relationship.  Ill have to do another join. Many thanks

Comment: No thanks required, better [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer, if it solved your problem. :)